# Assign relationship to struct members, automatically. (C)

Tags: c, struct

I defined a struct like below (in C).

```
struct Temp {
int C;
int F;};
```

and it is always true that

```
(C × 9/5) + 32 = F
```

Since I have several variables in type of "struct Temp", it would not be easy to define a subroutine to make the calculation and call it per each variable.
It would be a solution if the following code was possible.

```
struct Temp {
int C;
int F = (C × 9/5) + 32;};
```

How can I apply this relationship Automatically when a new variable in type of "struct Temp" is defined.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't. The best you can do is to write a function to initialize.

Comment: This is not possible with C primitives. Since the calculation is so easy, you could use a macro to convert C into F. This calculation is not cached, however, but since it is so simple this might not be a problem. If speed is important, you might even use a lookup table. This is well possible since you only use integer granularity and the used temperature range is probably not very big.

Comment: Anyway, it sounds like an XY-problem. There is no need to keep redundant information in the `struct` at all in most cases. You can do the conversion at a time it is needed (before displaying it or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by initializing the array, but for that, you have to first assign a value to C. E.g.

```
struct abc{
int a;
int b;
};
int z = 97;
struct abc pqr = {z, z+9/4};
```

Now the value of variable a in pqr is 4 and b is 6
You can do it by defining a macro as well. E.g.

```
#define    MYSTRUCT(NAME, VAL)    struct abc NAME = {VAL, VAL+9/4};
```

Then create a new struct as :

```
MYSTRUCT(pqr, 97);
printf("%d, %d", pqr.a, pqr.b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Structs are data types so you can't initialize a data type with a new value just like you can't manipulate the inner properties of an "int" data type. But we can define "ints" afterwards and so we can also do the same with "structs". Like the others said, you have to write a function to do this

the below is an example of using a function macro to do this painlessly. Note however that your types for C and F are both integer so they'll get truncated when trying to convert. Better to declare them as float or double.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define initF(x) (x.F = (x.C * 9/5) + 32)

struct Temp {
        int C;
        int F;
};
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        struct Temp t;
        t.C = 32;
        initF(t);
        printf("Temp F = %d\n", t.F);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called a Property which is not supported in C. You can do this in two ways, the first way is to define a function to do the calculation each time, like code below. This method is non-cached.

```
int GetF(struct Temp temp)
{
    return temp.C * 1.8 + 32;
}
```

The other way (cached) is to set the `C` value with a function in a way that calculates and saves the `F` value and you can use it later quickly.

```
int SetC(struct Temp temp, int c)
{
    temp.C = c;
    temp.F = c * 1.8 + 32;
}
```